# error C2039: 'sscanf' : is not a member of '`global namespace''

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

My cstdio file broke

the line:

using _CSTD sscanf;

is now underlined, with

error: the global scope has no "sscanf"

Error   44  error C2873: 'sscanf' : symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\cstdio   51

Error   47  error C2039: 'sscanf' : is not a member of '`global namespace'' C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\cstdio   51

edit: cstdio is a locked/Read-Only file, I didn't make any changes to it

Comment: Maybe it would help to show your code, no?

Comment: It's a huge solution with a lot of projects, and nothing is including cstdio directly :/

Comment: First, double-check if you can still compile a file with just #include <cstdio> (As part of your solution). Then, find out where cstdio is included indirectly.

Comment: Interesting.  Judging from what you're saying, the system header is no longer compiling because something — you're not sure what — changed.  Is that the only error, or is it just the first of many?  Does `_CSTD` appear elsewhere in the `cstdio` file?  Have you defined `_CSTD` somewhere, somehow?  (The name is reserved for the implementation, but if you set it to some value, you might get unexpected results — like this.)

Comment: try right-clicking on _CSTD - maybe you can "Jump to Definition" and find out if there's a bad definition of _CSTD around, as in @JonathanLeffler's theory

Comment: So this is a brand new blank solution, I can't even compile helloworld now

http://i.imgur.com/qwShioc.png

(same result if I just use #include <cstdio> in a blank file)